# Mysql query returning latest result for each element

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a hard time wrapping my mind around what seems should be a simply query.

So let's say we have a table that keeps track of amount of widgets/balloons in each store by date. How would you get a list of stores and their latest widget/balloons count?

i.e.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM inventory;
+----+------------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | invDate    | store | widgets | balloons|
+----+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 2011-01-01 |     3 |      50 |      35 |
|  2 | 2011-01-04 |     2 |      50 |      35 |
|  3 | 2013-07-04 |     3 |      12 |      78 |
|  4 | 2020-07-04 |     2 |      47 |      18 |
|  5 | 2020-08-06 |     2 |      16 |    NULL |
+----+------------+-------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Would like the result table to list all stores and their latest inventory of widgets/baloons

store, latest widgets, latest balloons

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| store |   widgets | baloons |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     2 |        16 |    NULL |
|     3 |        12 |      78 |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

or grab latest non NULL value for balloons.

Comment: Add ORDER BY invDate DESC and GROUP BY store to the end of your query.

Comment: @jhilgeman: It is not that easy

Comment: @meccooll: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Have few versions running and can update if there's an elegant solution on newer version but one of the older instances is mysqld  Ver 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for all versions of MySQL

```
select i.*
from inventory i
join
(
  select store, max(invDate) as maxDate
  from inventory
  group by store
) tmp on tmp.store = i.store 
     and tmp.maxDate = i.invDate
```

With MySQL 8+ you can do window functions:

```
with cte as
(
   select store, widgets, balloons, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY store ORDER BY invDate desc) AS rn
   from inventory
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Comment: That does it! Good to know that there wasn't some simple function that i was missing. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated sub query to get latest record for each store

```
select i.*
from inventory i
where i.invDate = (
    select max(invDate)
    from inventory
    where i.store = store
)
order by i.store
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93e6fb/2)

Comment: @juergend like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f845d7/1 ? I really don't get your statement , it should work if the date of 2 or more stores are same because of a correlated query